# How to extract item from nested list - Rest Assured

Tags: java, rest-assured

I've got this  json object

```
{
   "type" : "employee",
   "columns" :
      [
         {
            "id" : 1,
            "human" :
               [
                  {
                     "name" : "ANA",
                     "age" : "23"
                  },
                  {
                     "name" : "IULIA",
                     "age" : "22"
                  }
               ]
         },
         {
            "id" : 2,
            "human" :
               [
                  {
                     "name" : "ADI",
                     "age" : "21"
                  },
                  {
                     "name" : "GELU",
                     "age" : "18"
                  }
               ]
         }
      ]
}
```

and I need to extract the first name from each human list.
I've tried  `.body("columns.human.name[0]", everyItem(containsString("A")))` but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: `columns` and `human` are arrays; try `columns[i].human[j].name`

Comment: try `.body("columns[0].human[0].name"`  to check if you can get the first element of it

Answer (score 0):

Using `JsonPath` you can get all columns and all humans.

Each of `JSON Object` is represented as `HashMap<>`. If it contains only fields it's `HashMap<String, String>` but if contains arrays or nested JSON Objects then it is `HashMap<String, Object>` where `Object` is either another JSON Object or array.

Given the above you can use following code to get all columns and name of first human in each column:

```
JsonPath path = response.jsonPath();
List<HashMap<String, Object>> columns = path.getList("columns");
for (HashMap<String, Object> singleColumn : columns) {
    List<HashMap<String, Object>> humans = (List<HashMap<String, Object>>) singleColumn.get("human");
    System.out.println(humans.get(0).get("name"));
}
```

The above code will print `ANA` and `ADI` in the console.
You can store the results in `List<String>` for further processing

Answer (score 0):

you can get all "name" from humans with jsonPath : `$.columns[*].human[*].name` it will give below result :

```
[
  "ANA",
  "IULIA",
  "ADI",
  "GELU"
]
```

And if you want only first "name" then you need to use josn : `$.columns[*].human[0].name` this will give you below result:

```
[
  "ANA",
  "ADI"
]
```